# Multiple texture references in CUDA - use in kernel-time

Tags: cuda, textures

I have some data to be processed, with each block being responsible for a given subset of the data.

Due to the nature of my application, I want this data to reside in texture memory. However, the data is too big to fit in one single texture reference.

If I understood correctly, I can have multiple texture references, but not an array of texture references.

As I need to process a different subset of the data in each block, I was thinking of doing something (in the kernel) like

```
while(counter < 10000) {

 if(blockIdx.x == 0)
     foo = tex2D(tex0, x, y);

 else if(blockIdx.x == 1)
     foo = tex2D(tex1, x, y);

 ...

}
```

But not only is this bad to look at, I'm also not sure if I won't incur in divergence problems.

Doing something like

```
texture<int, 2, cudaReadModeElementType> ref;

(..)

/* kernel code from now on */

if(blockIdx.x == 0)
    ref = tex0;

else if(blockIdx.x == 1)
    ref = tex1;

...

while(counter < 10000)
    foo = tex2D(ref, x, y)
```

also doesn't quite seem right, as I believe texture references are global and not private to threads.

Is there any other alternative? Thank you.

Comment: Does the data really need to be in different textures to begin with?

Comment: just a remark: the maximal size of 2D texture bound to linear memory is 65000 x 65000 which is already 4Gb of mem. There are also 2D layered textures of maximal size 8k x 8k x 512 = 32 Gb.  
How much global memory does your graphics card have ?  I suppose just having few very large textures would be enough for any application

Comment: @talonmies Not really, but it doesn't fit into one single texture due to the size restrictions.

Comment: @asm My graphics card is a Tesla C2050, it has 3Gb of global memory. The data itself is around 2Gb in total. My issue when it comes to a single reference is the maximum value for the x dimension, which is exceeded by my data's size on x.

Comment: then you can also consider packing your data in 2D tiles for texturing. You might need to first "flatten" your data into 1D array and then repack it into 2D tiles of fixed size. Anyway, texture cache is optimized for 2D spatial locality, therefore using tiles is always benefitial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible, you should try to keep your texture data in a single texture, and apply some transformation to the coordinates as needed to fit within the hardware limitations.

Otherwise, you can select from multiple texture references via predication.  Only the non-predicated instruction will actually generate a texture memory reference.

The tex1dfetch_big.cu sample from The CUDA Handbook shows how to do this, to increase addressing beyond the 27-bit indices supported by the hardware.

https://github.com/ArchaeaSoftware/cudahandbook/blob/checkpoint/texturing/tex1dfetch_big.cu